# How to test that a jasmine custom matcher fails due to an exception in the matcher

Tags: jasmine, jasmine2.0

I have an odd looking test spec below.

```
expect(function(){
   expect(null).not.toEqualMoment(testContext.moment1);
}).toThrow();
```

The inner expectation fails because of the check below inside my custom matcher, which throws an exception.

```
if(!moment.isMoment(actual)) {
    throw new Error(_.string.sprintf('Actual: %s , is not a Moment object.', jasmine.pp(actual)));
}
```

I think an exception has to be thrown here and not just return a failing result because if not,
expect(null).not.toEqualMoment(null) will return true. ( If that makes sense to you ) .

So,
If I fail custom matchers with exceptions, how can I test this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your custom matcher, several problems occur when you do this by just apply your matchers.
For most simple custom matchers, you can just do `expect(actual).toBeCustom(expected)`. If the test passes, the matcher is ok.
For the inverted case, just add `.not`.

However, in this way you are not testing the internal workings of the matcher, like what message is returned when a matcher fails, or - in your case - that the matcher throws and exception. You tried to test this by nesting `expect` calls, which is not possible.

Therefore, you need to add the matcher itself to your test and test the `compare` method.

`expect(toEqualMomentMatcher.compare({}, momentjs())).toThrow('Actual: Object({  }) is not a Moment object');`

Apart from your question, I advice you to let the matcher fail if actual is not a Moment. Just return a different message when `actual` is not a Moment.